# use Enum in ListPreference

Tags: android, enums, android-preferences, listpreference

I have a pretty simple Enum that I am using throughout my application for Gender and I need to have a settings page where the user can change it, but I can't find any way to use an Enum in a ListPreference. I am using a PreferenceFragment to build the Preferences Screen, but I can't find a way to use the Enum I have as the entries and entryValues for the ListPreference.
The enum is very simple, just...

```
public enum Gender implements EnumSpinner {
  MALE("Male", 0),
  FEMALE("Female", 1),
  NONE("Prefer not to say", -1);

  private static SparceArray<Gender> genderMap = new SparceArray<>();

  static {
    for(Gender gender : Gender.values()) {
      genderMap.put(gender.getValue(), gender);
    }
  }

  private String name;
  private int value;

  Gender(String name, int value) {
    this.name = name;
    this.value = value;
  }

  public static Gender getGender(int val) { return genderMap.get(val); }

  @Override
  public String toString() { return name; }

  public String getName() { return name; }
  public int getValue() { return value; }
}
```

Is it possible to use in a ListPreference or am I going to have to create 2 string arrays in the strings.xml file and just use it that way?

SideNote, EnumSpinner is just an interface that allows me to use the enum in a spinner.

Answer (score 0):

I grew frustrated with the inconvenience of adding Enum to settings preferences. I came up with the following solution which saves you from having to do the tedious mapping of Enum values to list preference entry values. The result is a lot more readable, easier to maintain with less boilerplate.

Should soon be on the main branch of [Fulguris](https://github.com/Slion/Fulguris).

`EnumListPreference.kt`

```
package fulguris.preference

import acr.browser.lightning.R
import android.content.Context
import android.util.AttributeSet
import androidx.preference.ListPreference
import timber.log.Timber
import android.content.SharedPreferences

/**
 * [EnumListPreference] makes it easier to setup a [ListPreference] from an enum class.
 * Like [ListPreference] it stores its current value as a string through [SharedPreferences].
 * Values are derived from the Enum entry names through reflection.
 * Make sure you do not change the names of the Enum entries without understanding the consequences.
 * The XML resource must provide the enumClassName attribute as a string.
 * The defaultValue attribute should be the name of one of the Enum entries.
 */
class EnumListPreference (context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet) : ListPreference(context, attrs) {

    /**
     * Name of the enum class defining this preference
     */
     var enumClassName: String = ""
        set(value) {
            field = value
            generateEntryValuesFromEnum()
        }

    init {
        // Get attributes from XML
        val attributes = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.EnumListPreference)
        attributes.let {
            enumClassName = it.getString(R.styleable.EnumListPreference_enumClassName).toString()
            it.recycle()
            Timber.d(enumClassName)
        }
    }

    /**
     *
     */
    private fun generateEntryValuesFromEnum() {
        // TODO: Check if [Class.isEnum] and provide error logs if needed
        // See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52316667/3969362
        // Load entry values from specified enum class
        entryValues = (Class.forName(enumClassName)?.enumConstants as Array<Enum<*>>).map { it.name }.toTypedArray()
    }

}
```

`attr.xml`

```
    <declare-styleable name="EnumListPreference">
        <attr name="enumClassName" format="string" />
    </declare-styleable>
```

`preference.xml`

```
    <fulguris.preference.EnumListPreference
        a:key="@string/pref_key_launch_app"
        a:title="@string/settings_title_launch_app"
        a:useSimpleSummaryProvider="true"
        a:defaultValue="ASK"
        a:entries="@array/NoYesAsk"
        a:icon="@drawable/ic_apps"
        a:singleLineTitle="false"
        a:enumClassName="acr.browser.lightning.settings.NoYesAsk"
        />
```

`NoYesAsk.kt`

```
enum class NoYesAsk(val value: Int) {
    NO(0),
    YES(1),
    ASK(2)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Please check in the google developers youtube channel, Android Performance Matters there is a video explaining why you would prefer not using enums in Android, there are other ways to get the same functionality. 
Android has a Framework for Settings/Preferences, you can find an excellent tutorial here.

[Buuilding Settings Screen Android](https://medium.com/@JakobUlbrich/building-a-settings-screen-for-android-part-1-5959aa49337c)